# File compression/decompression of binary representations of integer lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, lossless-compression

Currently, I have a system that converts a list of integers to their binary representations. I calculate the number of bytes each number requires and then use the `to_bytes()` function to convert them to bytes, like so:

```py
o = open(outFileName, "wb")
for n in result:
    numBytes = math.ceil(n.bit_length()/8)
    o.write(n.to_bytes(numBytes, 'little'))

o.close()
```

However, since the bytes are of varying lengths, what would be the method to allow an unpacking program/function to know how long each byte was? I have heard uses of the struct module and specifically the pack function, but with a focus on efficiency and reducing the size of the file as much as possible in mind, what would be the best way of approaching this to allow such an unpacking program to retrieve the exact list of originally encoded integers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Your encoding maps different lists of integers to the same sequence of bytes. It is then impossible to know which one was the original input.

You need a different encoding.

Take a look at using the [high bit each byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity). There are other ways that might be better, depending on the distribution of your integers, such as [Golomb coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding).